# Using input and output operators for reading objects of user-defined-types

Tags: c++

I have been reading [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) and ran into this introductory code snippet about classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"
int main()
{
    Sales_item book;
    // read ISBN, number of copies sold, and sales price
    std::cin >> book;
    // write ISBN, number of copies sold, total revenue, and average price
    std::cout << book << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

- Don't you have to overload `operator>>` and `operator<<` functions for this code to compile?
- If that's the case, is it considered good practice to overload input and output operators for object manipulation instead of using constructors/setters and getters? I mean, is this a common thing and good to go for it?

Comment: You don't overload *objects* or *classes*, you overload *functions* (members and non-members), in your case the `operator<<` and `operator>>` functions. Start by reading about [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). [Here's an okay tutorial on overloading the input/output operators.](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/)

Comment: Most likely you will find the answers while reading further :) Yes, you have to overload operators >> and << for std::istream and std::ostream respectively.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the correction. Actually, that was what I meant, overloading the operators, even though I used incorrect terms as if I wanted to overload objects or classes. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is idiomatic C++ by grace of being in the standard library to use the bit-shifting operators for stream insertion and extraction.
That works because bit-shifting a stream-object has no sense ;-)
For the same reasons, `+` is acceptable for string concatenation.

Your observation that you have to define the overloads for `operator<<` and `operator>>` yourself is correct. But free functions are fine.
For all the details of operator-overloading (though not move semantics), there's this question: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, you must overload `istream >>` and `ostream <<` operators for the code to compile. Having read C++ Primer, they cover that in the later chapters.

2) This is primarily opinionated, but I feel that it is one of the *better* operators to overload, as it does make life a lot easier. The book overloads them for teaching purposes.

Comment: I expected some explanations in the beginning as opposed to what they did since this is considered an introductory text, I thought beginners might get confused. I don't know if I missed it but I was also expecting a mention for overloading operators for that program to work, in case someone wanted to compile and run the program. Seems like a good book tho, can't wait to finish it:)

Comment: @Varaquilex I have to say, the first chapter is extremely confusing. It just gives a brief overview of what the book the designed to cover.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to overload operator<< and operator>> for a user defined type if you want to stream it.
In my opinion stream operators, and getters and setters are for different kinds of behaviors so your second question looked like an apples to oranges comparison to me.  If you want to be able to fill the object directly from the stream, then overloading stream operators is the only way to do it.  Otherwise you'd have to stream into basic types first, and then use mutators.  Certainly you would not want to use operator overloading for all mutations of the object, but only when you are interfacing to streams.  You might need to define classes with stream overloading, and getters and setters.  It's not a mutually exclusive choice.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't overload std::cin and std::cout but operator << and operator >> of your class on a specific stream.
- In most cases you use getter and setter for manipulate your data but operators overload is useful when you want to manipulate your object as a whole and not only in simple cin/cout cases. You can put and get your object to every kind of stream.